# What sensors are avaliable from phone 7's API?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sensors

I know that windows phone 7 has 5 sensors: A-GPS, Accelerometer, Compass, Light, Proximity and microphone, WiFi, Bluetooth, Camera, etc.

I can access GPS, Accelerometer, Microphone and Camera. But I cannot find APIs for accessing the raw data of compass, light, proximity, WiFi and Bluetooth.

What I am in need now is to scan the WiFi frequently and get the nearly-by access points IDs. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't found the API for these functions because they aren't exposed in the SDK at the moment.

Compass was pulled before CTP for being just slightly below quality expectations, light and proximity aren't exposed at the moment, neither is bluetooth via the 3rd Party SDK.

Data is accessible via Wifi and Wifi contributes to the Location service. However you can't access low level wifi network data at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Mick! So it is not possible to get the WiFi access points list in range in the current API?

Comment: That's correct. Feel free to comment in the suggestions forum or on Connect (vs/wpdt) if/how you feel this would improve the platform.